# Finalize first element of an array

Tags: java, arrays, final, finalize

Say, I have some class which holds an array of integers in it.

```
Integer[] numbers;
```

Also, I have some simple constructor which initializes my array:

```
public Program()
{
    numbers = new Integer[11];
    numbers[0] = null;
}
```

As you can see, I have an array of `11` elements.

The point is that I will never ever change the first one with index `0`.

Is there a way to finalize the first element of my array, so it can't be changed?

Like with `final` variables.

Comment: Well, `Integer`s are immutable, if that's what you're asking...

Comment: Oh, sorry, there was a typo in my question. I've corrected it.

Comment: Nope. Take out the first element and put in a new `final` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do that with an array. In fact, inability to make array elements read-only is a major drawback of using arrays in situations when data could be modified externally.

The only approach to protect elements of your array is to encapsulate the array in a class that would check elements and indexes before performing modifications:

```
public class ArrayWithFixedFirst {
    private final Integer[] numbers = new Integer[11];
    public Integer get(int index) {
        return numbers[index];
    }
    public void set(int index, Integer value) {
        if (index == 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        numbers[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a way to specify that the first element of an array cannot be re-assigned.

I think your best bet would be to create a wrapper class for the array, and then ignore any attempts to re-assign the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Through encapsulation, you can allow/disallow the array modification.

```
public void updateArray(int position,int value){

if(position > 0 && position < numbers.length){

    numbers[position] = value;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not force an array to be unmodifiable. An alternative is using `Collections.unmodifiableList`. But the whole list will therefore be unmodifiable.

Answer (score 0):

Intriguing question, but I'm going to have to say no. Java arrays will not allow you to finalize just one element. You could possibly get the same functionality by writing a custom wrapper, but that begs the question, why? I don't know what application you're going for, but I would recommend wrapping a ten element array and decrementing your index by one, and returning null for the zero'th index

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd do it, but something like this:

```
class NoFirstArray extends ArrayList {
    public NoFirstArray(int size,Object initialValue) {
       super(size);
       super.set(0,initialValue);
    }
    public void set(Integer i, Object value) {
        if(i == 0) throw RuntimeException();
        super.set(i,value);
    }
    public void remove(int i) {
        if(i == 0) throw RuntimeException();
        super.remove(i);
    }
}
```